# Find the critical points of the function $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)$ and examine if they are local extremums.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, extreme-value-theorem

I have given a function $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)(y-2x^2)$.
I have to inspect its critical points and to see if they are actually local extremums.
I found the critical points by setting  $ \nabla f(x,y)=0$ and I got two critical points at $(0,0)$ and at $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3})$.

Then I calculated the Hesse-Matrix and I got $ H_{f}(x,y)= \begin{pmatrix}
12x-6y  & -6x\\ 
-6x & 2
\end{pmatrix} $

Therefore at $(0,0)$ : \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

I, then calculated the determinant and the trace since we are in two dimensions and I got $det H_{f}=0$ which means that this matrix is positive semidefinite which ,if I am not wrong, means that we cannot make any statement whether the point $(0,0)$ is a local extremum or a Minimum or Maximum.

So what can I do in this case to further examine if this point is a local extremum, is there any other way to find out.

I would really appreciate some (hopefully not so complicated) method that could help me in such cases.

Thank you in advance,

Annalisa

Comment: External graph theory is a completely different branch of mathematics which has nothing to do with your question. That's why I changed the tag. Look here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremal_graph_theory

Comment: I understand, thanks for your comment, I took my tag off.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\ne0$ and $y$ lies between $x^2$ and $2x^2$, then $f(x,y)<0$. But, if $y\ne0$, then $f(0,y)=y^2>0$. Therefore, $(0,0)$ is a saddle point of your function.